# Is there something wrong with my insert method and binsearch method?

Tags: c++, binary-search

I'm studying programming and there's an already created program of void `merge()`. I tried adding binary search method and insert method. The program should output a list of combined elements of array `A` and `B` in ascending order. The elements of `A` should be put to the elements of `B`. The output is wrong.

This is my output:

```
3 16
Inserting 512 into b at -1
2 0
61 154 170 275 426 509 612 653 677 703 765 897 908 512 503 512
```

And this is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int binsearch(int array[], int first, int last, int search_key)
{
    int index;

    if (first > last)
        index = -1;

    else
    {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;

        if (search_key == array[mid])
            index = mid;
        else

            if (search_key < array[mid])
                index = binsearch(array, first, mid - 1, search_key);
            else
                index = binsearch(array, mid + 1, last, search_key);

    } // end if
    return index;
}

void insert(int A[], int B[], int n, int m, int i){
    int j = n - m - 1, k = n - 1;
    while (i >= 0 && j >= 0){
        if (A[i] > B[j]){
            B[k--] = A[i--];
        }
        else {
            B[k--] = B[j--];
        }
    }
    if (j<0){
        while (i >= 0){
            B[k--] = A[i--];
        }
    }
}

void merge(int a[], int b[], int m, int n) {
    int a_size = m;
    int b_size = n;
    while (n != 0 && m != 0) {
        printf("%d %d\n", m, n);
        if (!(m > n)) {
            int t = log(n / m);
            int i = n + 1 - pow(2, t);
            if (a[m - 1] < b[i - 1]) {
                printf("Decreasing n\n");
                n = n - pow(2, t);
            }
            else {
                int k = binsearch(b, i - 1, n, a[m - 1]) + 1;
                printf("Inserting %d into b at %d\n", a[m - 1], k - 1);
                insert(a, b, b_size, k-3, m-1);
                b_size++;
                m = m - 1;
                n = k;
            }
        }
        else /* m > n */ {
            int t = log(n / m);
            int i = m + 1 - pow(2, t);
            if (b[n - 1] < a[i - 1]) {
                printf("Decreasing m\n");
                m = m - pow(2, t);
            }
            else {
                /*int k = binsearch(i - 1, m, b[n - 1], a) + 1;*/
                int k = binsearch(a, i - 1, m, b[n - 1]) + 1;
                printf("Inserting %d into a at %d\n", b[n - 1], k - 1);
                insert(b, a, a_size, k-3, n-1);
                a_size++;
                n = n - 1;
                m = k;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", m, n);
}

int main(){
    int m = 3;
    int n = 16;
    int A[] = { 87, 503, 512 };
    int B[] = { 61, 154, 170, 275, 426, 509, 612, 653, 677, 703, 765, 897, 908 };

    merge(A, B, m, n);

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d ", B[i]);
    }

    system("pause>0");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the program's logic:

> **Preliminary**: A is an array of integers of length m and B is an
>   array of integers of length n. Also the elements from both arrays are
>   distinct (from the elements in both arrays) and in ascending order.
>
> **Step 1**: if n or m is zero STOP. Otherwise if m>n, set t = [log
>   (m/n)] and go to Step 4, else set t = [log (n/m)].
>
> **Step 2**: compare A[m] with B[n + 1 – 2<sup>t</sup>]. If A[m] is smaller, set n = n – 2^t
>   and return to Step1.
>
> **Step 3**: using binary search (which requires
>   exactly t more comparisons), insert A[m] into its proper place among
>   B[n + 1 - 2<sup>t</sup> ] ... B[n]. If k is maximal such that B[k] < A[m], set m =
>   m - 1 and n = k. Return to Step1.
>
> **Step 4**: (Step 4 and 5 are like
>   2 and 4, interchanging the roles of n and m, A and B) if B[n] <
>   A[m+1-2<sup>t</sup> ], set m := m - 2<sup>t</sup> and return to Step 1.
>
> **Step 5**: insert
>   B[n] into its proper place among the A’s. If k is maximal such that
>   A[k] < B[n], set m = k and n = n - 1. Return to Step1.

Comment: This looks cool, what is the name of the algorithm? Binary search looks alright to me, except the overflow in the calculation of `mid`. I'll try to take a look tomorrow morning when I'm fresh.

Comment: It didn't specify what kind of algorithm it is. Okay thank you!

Comment: There's an incompatibility with the instruction assignments and C++. In C/C++, array indexes start at 0 and end at `length-1`.  Hence, when step 2 says, `compare A[m] with B[n+1-2*t]`, what does that mean since `A[m]` is out of range?  I'm guessing the algorithm is written such that array indices start at 1. So to implement this in C/C++, you have to interpret that as `A[m-1]`. Then that calls in to question every other array index computation for B, which I assume means "subtract 1".   Also, what is supposed to happen if `n+1-2*t` is less than 0 or greater than n?

Comment: @selbie i'm sorry, i copy pasted wrong. it should be 2^t

Comment: i'm guessing that `n+1-2^t` is the index of an array of A when put in the array of B

Comment: *If A[m] is smaller, set n = n – 2t and return to Step 1.*  Should that read: If A[m] is smaller, set `n = n – 2^t`  and return to Step 1.

Comment: yup, i didn't see that. @selbie

Comment: In step 3: it says:  *insert A[m] into its proper place among B[n + 1 - 2^t ] ... B[n].*  Does that mean *swap* A[m] with B[k], or does it mean replace it?  This problem stopped making sense...

Comment: Put the array of A[m] into B[n + 1 - 2^t ] until B[n]. I think this one is for inserting and sorting it in ascending order. @selbie

Comment: The tag say C++. Code style looks more like C. Please adapt the tag in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is because of the *binsearch*. I think you are using it wrongly.
*binsearch* returns `-1` if it cannot find an element, otherwise it returns the index of that element in the array. And I think your version of `binsearch` does exactly that as far as I can see and test.
You are searching for an element of one array (`A` or `B`) in the other array (`B` or `A`) . ***binsearch* returns `-1`, because `A` and `B` are distinct. `k` is always returned `-1`.**

In C/C++ arrays are fixed size. Once the size determined you cannot change it. `A`'s size is 3 and `B`'s size is 13. **It is an error to increase the size of the array.**

---

### Appendix

**Binsearch experiment**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

/* binsearch from The C Programming Language (Second Edition) */
int binsearch1(int search_val, int array[], int array_len) {

    int low, high, mid;

    low = 0;
    high = array_len - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (search_val < array[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (search_val > array[mid])
            low = mid + 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }

    return -1; /* no match */
}

/* binsearch from SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34246941/1566187 */
int binsearch2(int array[], int first, int last, int search_key) {
    int index;

    if (first > last)
        index = -1;

    else {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;

        if (search_key == array[mid])
            index = mid;
        else

            if (search_key < array[mid])
            index = binsearch2(array, first, mid - 1, search_key);
        else
            index = binsearch2(array, mid + 1, last, search_key);

    }
    return index;
}


/*
 * Comparing binsearch from reference book and So question
 */
int main() {
    int m = 3;
    int A[] = {87, 503, 512};

    int i = binsearch1(503, A, m);
    int j = binsearch2(A, 0, m - 1, 503);

    cout << "Elements are found at indices" << endl;
    cout << i << ", " << j << endl;

    i = binsearch1(99, A, m);
    j = binsearch2(A, 0, m - 1, 99);

    cout << "Element are not found, thus return is -1" << endl;
    cout << i << ", " << j << endl;

    return 0;
}
```